# Log file creation in MFC (VC++)?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I want to create a Log file in MFC that should write to log file everytime it should append the logging details , it should not overrite the exisiting details.And there should be some size limit like if after this much size a new file should create.

How to achieve this?
any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [CStdioFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a499td6y%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) Class, specifically the method [CStdioFile::WriteString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1kysdae.aspx). It makes it easy to write text to a file.

When you open the file you want to combine the `CFile::modeCreate` and `CFile::modeNoTruncate` flags to create the file only if it doesn't exist already.

You can get the size of the file using the [CFile::GetLength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b569d0t4.aspx) method.

Comment: Can you pls share some sample ?

Comment: @swapnil: Sorry, haven't done MFC in many years so have no code around but this page has a basic sample: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7b61hcx0%28v=VS.100%29.aspx and here's another one: http://simplesamples.info/Beginners/CStdioFile.php

Answer (score 0):

Hi i dont know can you use external libs but log4cpp very good lib and you dont need write your own realisation of logger class
[link text](http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from CStdioFile, I also use [WritePrivateProfileString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725501%28VS.85%29.aspx) with the date and time as key name. You can thus add log strings in this form:

```
[LOG]
5-2-2010 15:06:10:804=Starting program...
5-2-2010 15:04:53:815=Data updated succesfully.
```